# XAML DoubleAnimation how to make circle picture to flip smoothly without tact repeat

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, animation

I am trying to improve my picture flipping (spinning)like a coin flip. This is already implemented, but picture in one frame moment always stop in one frame ant then continues again flip. Do you guys have any idea how it could work smoothly?

```
<DoubleAnimation From="0" 
    To="-1"
    BeginTime="00:00:01"
    Duration="00:00:00.350"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
<DoubleAnimation From="-1" To="0"
    BeginTime="00:00:01"
    Duration="00:00:00.350"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
```

And here is picture:

```
<Border x:Name="Logo" BorderBrush="White"
                    BorderThickness="4"
                    Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    CornerRadius="50"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Image    Source="pack://application:,,,/Application.Platform.Views;component/Resources/Applicationlogo.png"
                    Width="80" Height="80" />
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1"/>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
```

Thanks for answers or suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having access to your image, I created a simple border object to do what you intend.  With this type of animation, you need to be very precise with your `BeginTime` and `Duration` values.

```
<Border Width="50" Height="50" Background="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
  <Border.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform x:Name="st" ScaleX="1"/>
  </Border.RenderTransform>
  <Border.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">

          <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0"
                           Duration="0:0:0.333"
                           Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"/>
          <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="-1"
                           BeginTime="0:0:0.333"
                           Duration="0:0:0.333"
                           Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"/>
          <DoubleAnimation From="-1" To="0"
                           BeginTime="0:0:0.666"
                           Duration="0:0:0.333"
                           Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"/>
          <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1"
                           BeginTime="0:0:0.999"
                           Duration="0:0:0.333"
                           Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Border.Triggers>
</Border>
```

Also, you have to include `DoubleAnimation` blocks for each part of the "rotation" of the image; full-front to edge, edge to full-back, full-back to edge, and then edge to full-front.  That takes your animation back to the starting point and allows it to repeat smoothly.

You might be able to do it with 2 animation blocks; full-front to full-back and then full-back to full-front (1 to -1, -1 to 1) but I haven't tested that.

**EDIT:**

It works with just two `DoubleAnimation` blocks:

```
          <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="-1"
                           Duration="0:0:0.666"
                           Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"/>
          <DoubleAnimation From="-1" To="1"
                           BeginTime="0:0:0.666"
                           Duration="0:0:0.666"
                           Storyboard.TargetName="st"
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"/>
```

If you wanted to make it more realistic, you would include an easing function in the 4-step animation to simulate the perceived rate-of-change scaling in an object that is actually rotating.  The visible 'width' of the rotating object (from the observer's point of view) actually changes as a function of the sine of the rotation angle/speed rather than as a linear function like the example above.